# How to find DNS name of Virtual Machines in XenServer using Command line?

Tags: virtual-machine, citrix, xen

I am new to `XenServer`, so the question might be a little stupid.

I need to create a list of Virtual Machines on XenServer with a few details like

- IP
- DNS name
- OS version.. etc.

I have to write a java code for that, which I am doing by getting info from executing commands on XenServer via ssh.

When I run `xe vm-list` on a XenServer, the name-label parameter gives the name of VM as per the name of VM in XenCenter and not the real DNS name.

```
uuid ( RO)           : ebd360d4-4f98-b503-e418-0d9d1b6aa626
     name-label ( RW): Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (1)
    power-state ( RO): running
```

IP and OS, I can get by adding different params to the above command. How do I get the DNS name of the Virtual Machines?

Comment: When you say DNS name what are you talking about hostname ?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. I want to know the hostnames of the VMs . Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 0):

The hostnames of the VMs are isolated from the hypervisor. I am not sure if any kind of abstraction exists for fetching a hostname from outside a VM. Some network parameters such as IP are visible....but not much in terms of hostname. To make things a bit more difficult, nslookup and dig are not installed on the hosts themselves, so extracting the hostname via XenServer host shell commands will be difficult, unless such software is manually installed.

As a cheap alternative, you could name your VMs to be exact name the FQDN or hostname is, or will be, and then pull up the name-label via the host-param-get command.

```
 xe vm-param-get uuid=ebd360d4-4f98-b503-e418-0d9d1b6aa626 param-name=name-label
```